# Ellegant find regEx in array

Tags: javascript, regex, underscore.js

I want to launch one script if one off several browsers are detected. I made an array with regulars and I want to check if one of them exists in navigator.userAgent string. I want to do it with underscore without FOR EACH.

```
var browsers = [/chrome/, /opera/];
/* something like: */ 
if (!_.contains(browsers, navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) return;
```

Comment: You _do_ understand that underscore simply loops through all elements with something like a `for`, right?

Comment: of course, I do. I just want to make my code more beautiful

Comment: Okay. In that case, you'd be looking for [`_.some()`](http://underscorejs.org/#some), if you want to do it with underscore. However, dystroy's answer is much better (faster, cleaner, shorter...).

Comment: Please write an example of this _.some for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `_.some()`:

```
if (!_.some(browsers, function(item){
     return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().test(item);
}) return;
```

However, I'd recommend using [@dystroy's single-regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26212084/1835379). It's faster, shorter code.

You could do that like this:

```
var arr = ["chrome", "opera"]; // Strings, not regexes.
var regexp = new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'i');
if (!regexp.test(navigator.userAgent)) return;
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
if (!RegExp(["chrome", "opera"].join('|'), 'i').test(navigator.userAgent)) return;
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to have only one regex, so that you don't have to iterate. And using the `i` flag lets you avoid the `toLowerCase` :

```
if (!/chrome|opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) return;
```

Comment: Good solution. But I need to use array, this comes from database. So how to implement an array in your code?
if (!/ + arr.join('|') + /i.test(navigator.userAgent)) return;

Comment: If you have an array, use _.some as said by Cerbrus, don't bother trying to build a composite regex. But having this in a database is, to say the least, very suspect. The design of your application doesn't look right.